# SVN delete issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I delete a file **test.aspx.cs** directly from the Repo-browser in SVN.

But when ever I commit the folder of this test.aspx.cs , it shows conflict error although the file on the server is not longer there.

So I have to uncheck it in order to commit other files.

How can I remove this test.aspx.cs from showing up in the dialogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is deleted on the server and not in your local working copy, try doing an update before you commit.